# iPhone app that records audio during specific time

Tags: iphone, applications, audio

I was looking for an app that records audio during specific time.

For example: I want talk for 1 minute and this app should record just 1 minute. The audio recording should be stopped after this time automatically.

Answer (score 1):

try this [free app](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/quickvoice-recorder/id284675296?mt=8)

Some of the features:Compare These Features:

- One Touch Recording
- One Touch Stop & File Saved
- Super Small MP4 Recording File Sizes
- Send Voice Emails Up to 5MB
- Records for Seconds or Hours
- Pause Record and Resume
- Adjustable Recording Qualities
- Flip Mode For Mic on Top Recording
- Record Timer and Playback Counter
- Double Tap for Quick Playbacks
- Auto File Naming w/Optional Renaming
- Finger Scroll Through Messages
- Pause Play and Resume Modes
- Drag Slider for Seek/RWND/FFWD
- Audio Level VU Meter
- Displays File Sizes and Time Stamps
- Plays Thru Earpiece, Speaker, Ear Buds
- Use Devices' Built-In or Add-On Mics
- Ringtone Recording Feature
- EZ Sync Recordings to Computer
- Great Visual Voicemail Like Interface
- Voice Reminder Notes
- Send Voice Notes Through Apple's iMessages

Comment: this function doesn't exist in the app =/